# rpmbuild is looking for wrong SOURCES directory

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to package a collection of python and png files. No compile involved. I do this via following commands

```
mkdir -p $(WORKDIR)/rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,RPMS/noarch,SOURCES,SPECS}
cp utp.spec $(WORKDIR)/rpmbuild/SPECS
tar  -zcf $(WORKDIR)/rpmbuild/SOURCES/utp-1.0.tgz --exclude={*.swp,.git,.gitignore,utp.spec,makefile} -C .. ./utp
rpmbuild -ba utp.spec
```

and I get the following error:

```
medi@medi:~/work/utp> rpmbuild -v -ba utp.spec
error: Bad source: /home/medi/rpmbuild/SOURCES/utp-1.0.tgz: No such file or directory
```

First hint is rpmbuild should be looking into '/home/medi/work/rpmbuild/SOURCE/*.tgz'. Note missing 'work/'. So somehow rpmbuild is not reading my intention. Logic suggests that it would be something in utp.spec file. Here is my spec file

```
medi@medi:~/work/utp> cat utp.spec
Name:       utp
Version:    1.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    Universal Test Platform

Group:      Applications/Engineering
License:    Proprietary
URL:        http://www.example.com
Source0:    %{name}-%{version}.tgz

# BuildRequires:    
# Requires: 

%description
some description


%prep
%setup -q


%build
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}


%install
%make_install


%files
%doc



%changelog
```

Also, most likely I don't need all the spec directives. Please let me know which I should drop.

Comment: update .... I figured out that I need to instruct rpmbuild to look into the proper directory via `rpmbuild --define "_topdir $(WORKDIR)/rpmbuild" -ba utp.spec`

Comment: update ... I now get this error `+ cd utp-1.0
/home/medi/work/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.zUsev4: line 32: cd: utp-1.0: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.zUsev4 (%build)
` something in my spec must be wrong, why is it trying to `cd utp-1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
%setup -q
```

expects you **source** tgz to contain a directory named `%name-%version` hence `utp-1.0`. If the name of the directory inside your tgz is different, you can use:

```
%setup -q -n <subdir-name>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I have too many macros in my spec file for a noarch pkg. I see traces of gcc flags and arch like `RPM_BUILD_ROOT="/home/medi/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/utp-1.0-1.el8.x86_64"
` My pkg has bunch of python files and png files. that is it.

Comment: Can someone offer a simple noarch spec file for bunch of scripts. No build, no compile. Assume foo.tgz is in SOURCES/

Answer (score 0):

rpmbuild --define "_topdir /home/medi/work/rpmbuild" -v -ba utp.spec
or for only source folder
rpmbuild --define "_sourcedir /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/SOURCE/" -v -ba utp.spec

you can use these commands to control where it can look for things.